# Changing interface in C++

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am reading an article on extension of interface at following link.

http://wiki.hsr.ch/APF/files/ExtensionInterface.pdf

It has been mentioned here on page 142

> Over time the addition of these requests can bloat the interface with
>   functionality not anticipated in the initial framework design. If new
>   methods are added to the  "universalComponent" interface directly, all
>   client code must be updated and recompiled. This is tedious and
>   error-prone.

My question is (Assume we are using C++ to develop)

Why we have to compile client code if we add new methods to interface and not
modifying any existing functions in interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't read the article, but for starters, I would suggest to de-emphasize the terms "method" and "interface" in C++. Those terms are popular in strict OO languages like Java, but C++ is a broader, multi-paradigm language.

With that said, "adding methods to interfaces" is really just adding more virtual member functions to a base class. Changing the base class changes the *definition* of all derived classes, and thus all code that requires the complete type of any derived class *or* of the base class must be recompiled.

C++ types are *not* a runtime feature. Types only exist at compile time, and the *compiler* must have full access to the type definitions. (Again in contrast to other languages!) The interface-implementation relationship exists purely at compile-time and cannot be "precompiled". So there's really no such thing as "modifying the interface" that would produce runtime-modularity. The "interface" concept is just a neat mnemonic that you can use when designing your application, but it does not save you from recompiling. Changing a class definition changes the internal representation of the class, and you cannot (in general) make a correct C++ program unless *all* parts of the program see the same class definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a method to a class that is involved in polymorphism (means it has at least one virtual member function) potentially changes the binary layout of objects of that class and it's subclasses.